# Correctly nesting a PSCustomObject

Tags: powershell

I've spent all day trying to figure this out.

I am trying to create a PSCustomObject that when exported to a `Json` file via `ConvertTo-Json` it will have this sort of structure:

```
{

    "Name":

    {

        "Trigger": "My Trigger",

        "Description": "Do this"        

        "body":

        [

            "Command one"

            "Command two"

            "Command three"

        ]

    }

}
```

This is how I am declaring my `$PSCustomObject` :

```
$myObject = [PSCustomObject]@{

    Name = @(

    Trigger = 'My Trigger'

    Description = 'Do this'

    body = @(

        'Command one'

        'Command two'

        'Command three'

    )

}
```

But when I try to run the above code, I am getting errors such as:

```
Trigger: 
Line |
   5 |          Trigger = 'My Trigger'
     |          ~~~~~~~
     | The term 'Trigger' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
Description:
```

And any any variation I try just gives me more errors.
Any help would be greatly welcome!

Comment: If you want to correctly emulate your Json, change `Name = @(` for `Name = [ordered]@{` and there is a missing closing `}` in your code.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon It woorks! thanks allot, also that `[ordered` tip you three in there propably save me another day. I kid you not. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're nesting `[pscustomobject]` instances, the same syntax applies to the outer and the inner instance, which, for object *literals*, is a `[pscustomobject]` cast applied to a [*hasthable*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) literal:<sup>[1]</sup>

```bash
$myObject = [PSCustomObject] @{
  Name = [PSCustomObject] @{
    Trigger     = 'My Trigger'
    Description = 'Do this'
    body        = @(
      'Command one'
      'Command two'
      'Command three'
    )
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if the intent is to convert to JSON, consider `[ordered]` hasthable instances, which are comparatively more light-weight (`[ordered]` ensures that the definition order of the entries is preserved):

```bash
$myObject = [ordered] @{
  Name = [ordered] @{
    Trigger     = 'My Trigger'
    Description = 'Do this'
    body        = @(
      'Command one'
      'Command two'
      'Command three'
    )
  }
}
```

---

<sup>[1] Strictly speaking, no casting is involved: the syntax is *syntactic sugar* that directly constructs a `[pscustomobject]`, as evidenced by the fact that the definition order of the hashtable entries is preserved, which stand-alone hashtable literals do *not* do.</sup>

Comment: Wonderfull. This is perfect and I really appreciate your explanation for the syntax apllying to the outer/inner. Thing is I was actually using a text file with simple `key=value` pairs and then using the `convertfrom-data` and `ConvertTo-Json` command. but I just gave up on that  because hashtables dont seem to support multiple values to for one key. Just to be certain,I would like to ask, I am I wrong in this? It would be wonderfull if Hashtables could assign multiple values to a single key (arrays). Thanks anyways